# Android browser not using font-family while input

Tags: android, css, browser, fonts, textarea

I have a text area element that need to be styled to monospace font. I have the font-family set as monospace. However this works on Chrome mobile and desktop, on Android's browser keeps displaying the default font while inputing text until other element get focused.

```
    .content-text, .context-text:focus{
      font-family : monospace ;
    }
```

Comment: Does the Android browser have some different default stylesheet than the regular ones? You could check by putting the style inline in the element itself: `<textarea style="font-family:monospace">` That should override things.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the Android browser at the moment. But, shouldn't a given class rule override any defaults?

Answer (score 0):

check your @font-face, is it compatible with android?
check this blog post:
http://www.brianhadaway.com/font-face-declarations-on-android-devices/

use code snippet on here or that post to solve the problem.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'MyFont';
src: url('MyFont.eot?') format('eot'), url('MyFont.woff') format('woff'), url('MyFont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('MyFont.svg#webfontwTBKaDwa') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However this doesn't solve the problem. The font is indeed in the browser, as it is one of the default font-family in any browser (monospace) and it is displaying when the textarea element is on blur.